# Can you find the issue with the scroll to anchor in my dev site?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a twitter bootstrap page that I'm working on:

http://www.clearsoftinc.com/Clearsoft/public_html/services.html

The left nav is using javascript to scroll to anchors when items are selected.  For example, select "Software Engineering" and then "Agile Development" in the left nav.  See how the "Agile Development" section of the content area now aligns nicely with the top of the left nav.

The problem is that if you try to go to that same section of the content using a URL, the content doesn't align properly with the left nav.  So go here:  http://www.clearsoftinc.com/Clearsoft/public_html/services.html#softeng-agiledevelopment

... and notice that the content area is not properly lining up with the left nav.

Could you help me find the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it, you'll notice that the difference is the scroll on the page load doesn't take the header height into account.

You might want to delay your "scroll to the element" logic (if in javaScript) to wait a bit until the page has finished rendering.  Or in this case "bump" that logic again after the document ready.

Comment: Since this javascript is called from within jQuery's .ready() block, isn't this already doing as you suggest?  Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't really sure without taking the time to really snoop through your code, that is just the "symptom" having a lot to do with the header.  Given that it is twitter bootstrap, it is doing a lot of things with that header nav (to change it up based on width, add the collapsy magic etc.) Could be that the other stuff twitter is doing with that header is affecting/happening before or after your stuff.  You might be able to make a change with your CSS so that the header height is defined and fixed which should help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out there was a setTimeout(function(), 100) in some of the bootstrap scrollspy implementation that had to be changed to (function(), 300) in order to let some of the bootstrap magic happen before scrolling.